# I can't return the response from axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, return, axios

I'm trying to create a module in node to return a json from API using axios request. But when i try to return the response out of the function `getJson()`, nothing is returned to me.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const authentication = require('./authentication');


const url = `https://api.codenation.dev/v1/challenge/dev-ps/generate-data?token=${authentication.token}`;

const getJson = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  // Here i can see the json normally
  console.log(response.data)
  return response.data
}

const response = getJson()
// but here nothing is shows to me in console.
console.log(response)
```

[return of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkGqQ.png)

Comment: Your `getJson` function is an `async` function, which means that it returns a Promise instance. You have to wait for the promise in another `async` function with `await` or else add a `.then()` callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

`getJson()` is actually returning a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance. You will just need to `await` on that like:

```
(async () => {
  const response = await getJson()
  console.log(response)
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because `const response = getJson()` is executing it's code before `getJson` runs because it's async and the response is not arriving at that instance when it's executed.

```
# This code runs and executes some point in future when response arrives
const getJson = async ()=>{
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  //Here i can see the json normally
  console.log(response.data)
  return response.data
}

# This code runs and executes immediately which doesn't have response yet
const response = getJson()
```

Comment: I got it Thomas! thanks. In this case, do i need to do another async function wrapping the const to force wait the return from getJson()?

Comment: Yes, you will another async function for it or you can use IIFE - immediately invoked function expression like I have shared.